# Encoded URL how to Get Query String Values

Tags: php

I feel i am doing some basic mistake in getting query string values in ecoded URL via PHP.

Can anybody please guide whats teh best way to get query String values in PHP from below URL.

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwwww.mycompany.org%2FmyStatusListener%3FmtmId%3D%25MTMID%25%26statusCode%3D%25  -
STATUSCODE%25%26statusDate%3D%25STATUSDATE%25%26mnc%3D%25MNC%25%26mcc%3D%25MNC%25%26  -
blocked%3D%25BLOCKED%25%0A
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just use rawurldecode, parse_url and parse_str like so :

```
$a="http%3A%2F%2Fwwww.mycompany.org%2FmyStatusListener%3FmtmId%3D%25MTMID%25%26statusCode%3D%25STATUSCODE%25%26statusDate%3D%25STATUSDATE%25%26mn25MNC%25%26mcc%3D%25MNC%25%26blocked%3D%25BLOCKED%25%0A";
$b=rawurldecode($a);
$c=parse_url($b,PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($c,$d);
print_r($d);
```

Comment: This one is the better

Answer (score -1):

Use [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) see example here http://codepad.org/jANpV0Vz

**UPDATE:**

Example:

```
$s = 'http%3A%2F%2Fwwww.mycompany.org%2FmyStatusListener%3FmtmId%3D%25MTMID%25%26statusCode%3D%25STATUSCODE%25%26statusDate%3D%25STATUSDATE%25%26mnc%3D%25MNC%25%26mcc%3D%25MNC%25%26blocked%3D%25BLOCKED%25%0A';

$url = urldecode($s);

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$elements = explode('&', $query);
$result = array();

foreach ($elements as $element) {
   list($k, $v) = explode('=', $element);
   $result[$k] = $v;
}
print_r($result);
```